# laravel - add conditions to relationships

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two models "Channels" and "Schedules" with the relationship one Channel has many Schedules (one-to-many). What i want to do is get the channels that are containing schedules for today and schedules need to be sort ASC to the date also limit 10 schedules per Channel.

i wrote the following code but it returns wrong results sometimes. i checked for it and found laravel generating a SQL query so limiting the schedule results for all channels. i'm using Eloquent. anyone know how to do this?... Thanks.

```
$channels = $this->channels->whereHas('tvSchedules', function($q)
                {
                    $q->where('day', date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Carbon::now()->toDateString())))
                        ->where('end_time', '>=', Carbon::now()->toTimeString());

                })->with(['tvSchedules' => function($q){
                    $q->where('day', date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Carbon::now()->toDateString())))
                        ->where('end_time', '>=', Carbon::now()->toTimeString())
                        ->with('tvScheduleImages')
                        ->take(10)
                    ;
                }]);
```

---

```
SQL:

select * from `trn_tv_schedule` where `trn_tv_schedule`.`channel_id` in (1, 2) and `day` = '2015-08-31' and `end_time` >= '06:11:34' limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using eloquent relationships in the models
like

```
// Channel Model
public function schedules()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Schedule');
}
// Schedule Model
public function Channel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Channel');
}
```

if you are using laravel 5.0 then have a look at this - [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)